# Does adding rel=dofollow dynamically affect SEO?

Tags: seo, google-search, html, dofollow

As you know, `rel="dofollow"` increases the Google page rank of a website added to the href link, but what if I generate it dynamically with JavaScript - does Google still understand it or should I only add it to the HTML statically?

Answer (score 0):

text
text
Have exactly the same effect in SEO.
rel="nofollow" loose PageRank, but rel=do follow doesn't add more PageRank than no rel= mention.

So it's useless to try to add any rel dofollow mention in JavaScript.